# How to specify what to remove in a file using Python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to create a Python program that will take an html file full of my bookmarks, read its contents, delete everything except what I want to keep, and then save the remainder in a CSV file with just the URL and webpage name for each entry.

I have managed to get Python to open and read through the html file and store its contents in a .csv file, but I have no idea how to tell it to remove some parts and keep the rest. As an example, I have a subfolder called "February" and I want to put only the contents of that folder in the CSV file. Of those contents, I want to store only the URL and webpage name for all the bookmarked sites in that "February" folder.

My only knowledge of how to discriminate what to keep and what to remove is the lstrip() method, but that hardly works. My programming vocabulary is also poor so I have no idea how to "officially" describe what I want to do, making my search for help more difficult.

Can anyone help me out? I am at a total loss right now.

EDIT: Including all the code I have so far:

```
with open("bookmarks_3_6_17.html",'r',errors='ignore') as file:
    content=file.read()
#Gets the contents of the bookmarks html file

with open("bookmarks.csv",'w') as file:
    file.write(content)
    file.seek(0)
    file.lstrip('<DT>')
```

EDIT 2: Here's an example of some of the code I want to work with. Let's say that from the "Foods" bookmark folder in the html file, I want to get only the contents of the "Pasta" subfolder into a .csv file, and of those contents, I only want to get the URL and webpage name for each bookmarked page.

```
<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>
<!-- This is an automatically generated file.
     It will be read and overwritten.
     DO NOT EDIT! -->
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>
<H1>Bookmarks</H1>
<DL><p>
        <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1417261149" LAST_MODIFIED="1488711452">Foods</H3>
        <DL><p>
            <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1480251437" LAST_MODIFIED="1483641856">Pasta</H3>
            <DL><p>
                <DT><A HREF="http://paleoleap.com/quick-and-easy-paleo-stir-fries/" ADD_DATE="1423327839" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Quick And Easy Paleo Stir-Fries | Paleo Leap</A>
                <DT><A HREF="http://allrecipes.com/recipe/11951/linguine-with-clam-sauce/" ADD_DATE="1480251695" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Linguine with Clam Sauce Recipe - Allrecipes.com</A>
                <DT><A HREF="http://www.food.com/recipe/tuscan-vegetarian-pasta-392763?photo=376155" ADD_DATE="1480251701" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Tuscan Vegetarian Pasta Recipe - Food.com: Food.com</A>
                <DT><A HREF="http://www.cheatsheet.com/life/8-deliciously-rustic-pasta-recipes-no-tomato-sauce-required.html/?a=viewall" ADD_DATE="1480251706" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">8 Deliciously Rustic Pasta Recipes, No Tomato Sauce Required</A>
                <DT><A HREF="http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/giada-de-laurentiis/penne-with-sun-dried-tomato-pesto-recipe.html" ADD_DATE="1480251830" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Penne with Sun-Dried Tomato Pesto Recipe : Giada De Laurentiis : Food Network</A>
                <DT><A HREF="http://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/mediterranean_tuna_pasta/" ADD_DATE="1480329433">Mediterranean Tuna Pasta Recipe | SimplyRecipes.com</A>
            </DL><p>
            <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1480251449" LAST_MODIFIED="1485183080">Chicken</H3>
            <DL><p>
                <DT><A HREF="http://www.food.com/recipe/chicken-rice-and-spices-bake-105104" ADD_DATE="1476195335" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Chicken, Rice, And Spices Bake Recipe - Food.com</A>
                <DT><A HREF="http://chefsavvy.com/recipes/honey-barbecue-chicken-bites/" ADD_DATE="1471006227" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Honey Barbecue Chicken Bites - Chef Savvy</A>
                <DT><A HREF="http://www.food.com/recipe/simple-easy-stuffed-roast-chicken-with-gravy-for-beginners-101998?nl=email_share" ADD_DATE="1467453921" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Simple Easy Stuffed Roast Chicken With Gravy For Beginners) Recipe - Food.com</A>
                <DT><A HREF="http://www.thekitchn.com/winter-casserole-recipe-simple-shepherds-pie-recipes-from-the-kitchn-179722" ADD_DATE="1480251630" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Winter Casserole Recipe: Shepherd&#39;s Pie — Recipes from The Kitchn | The Kitchn</A>
                <DT><A HREF="http://www.food.com/recipe/my-quot-famous-quot-shredded-chicken-205760" ADD_DATE="1485178904" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">My famous Shredded Chicken Recipe - Food.com</A>
            </DL>
```

Comment: Add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: You want an HTML parser. Take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html

Comment: Sembei, thanks for the link, I will check that out immediately!

Comment: It is difficult to answer this without knowing the contents of the file. Can you provide a small example, highliting the things you want to keep and the things you want to discard?

Comment: Hi @Petar, I added an example of the file I am working with.

Comment: Ok, so @SembeiNorimaki is right in that using an HTML parser would be the easiset way to do this. Have you tried to the `HTMLParser` library? The examples on that page should be sufficient. If you want to build a solution yourself, without using a library, you can use Python's built-in string manpulation methods like `.find()` and `.replace()` which would be particularly useful. When I have some time I will put together an example of the `HTMLParser` approach.

Comment: Thanks @Petar! Honestly I am extremely new to programming and this is my first attempt at making a script all by myself. I'm sure the HTMLParser library is what I'm looking for so I will check it out. I also look forward to what you send my way. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be enough to get you going. It returns the URL and the title of the page.

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
  def __init__(self):
    HTMLParser.__init__(self)
    self.my_tag = ''

  def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    self.my_tag = tag
    if tag == 'a':
      for name, value in attrs:
        if name == 'href':
          print value

  def handle_data(self, data):
    if self.my_tag == 'a':
      print data

# this text variable holds the contents of your file        
text = '<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1><!-- This is an automatically generated file.     It will be read and overwritten.     DO NOT EDIT! --><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE><H1>Bookmarks</H1><DL><p>        <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1417261149" LAST_MODIFIED="1488711452">Foods</H3>        <DL><p>            <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1480251437" LAST_MODIFIED="1483641856">Pasta</H3>            <DL><p>                <DT><A HREF="http://paleoleap.com/quick-and-easy-paleo-stir-fries/" ADD_DATE="1423327839" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Quick And Easy Paleo Stir-Fries | Paleo Leap</A>                <DT><A HREF="http://allrecipes.com/recipe/11951/linguine-with-clam-sauce/" ADD_DATE="1480251695" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Linguine with Clam Sauce Recipe - Allrecipes.com</A>                <DT><A HREF="http://www.food.com/recipe/tuscan-vegetarian-pasta-392763?photo=376155" ADD_DATE="1480251701" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Tuscan Vegetarian Pasta Recipe - Food.com: Food.com</A>                <DT><A HREF="http://www.cheatsheet.com/life/8-deliciously-rustic-pasta-recipes-no-tomato-sauce-required.html/?a=viewall" ADD_DATE="1480251706" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">8 Deliciously Rustic Pasta Recipes, No Tomato Sauce Required</A>                <DT><A HREF="http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/giada-de-laurentiis/penne-with-sun-dried-tomato-pesto-recipe.html" ADD_DATE="1480251830" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Penne with Sun-Dried Tomato Pesto Recipe : Giada De Laurentiis : Food Network</A>                <DT><A HREF="http://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/mediterranean_tuna_pasta/" ADD_DATE="1480329433">Mediterranean Tuna Pasta Recipe | SimplyRecipes.com</A>            </DL><p>            <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1480251449" LAST_MODIFIED="1485183080">Chicken</H3>            <DL><p>                <DT><A HREF="http://www.food.com/recipe/chicken-rice-and-spices-bake-105104" ADD_DATE="1476195335" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Chicken, Rice, And Spices Bake Recipe - Food.com</A>                <DT><A HREF="http://chefsavvy.com/recipes/honey-barbecue-chicken-bites/" ADD_DATE="1471006227" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Honey Barbecue Chicken Bites - Chef Savvy</A>                <DT><A HREF="http://www.food.com/recipe/simple-easy-stuffed-roast-chicken-with-gravy-for-beginners-101998?nl=email_share" ADD_DATE="1467453921" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Simple Easy Stuffed Roast Chicken With Gravy For Beginners) Recipe - Food.com</A>                <DT><A HREF="http://www.thekitchn.com/winter-casserole-recipe-simple-shepherds-pie-recipes-from-the-kitchn-179722" ADD_DATE="1480251630" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Winter Casserole Recipe: Shepherd&#39;s Pie — Recipes from The Kitchn | The Kitchn</A>                <DT><A HREF="http://www.food.com/recipe/my-quot-famous-quot-shredded-chicken-205760" ADD_DATE="1485178904" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">My famous Shredded Chicken Recipe - Food.com</A>            </DL>'

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed(text)
```

This outputs:

```
http://paleoleap.com/quick-and-easy-paleo-stir-fries/
Quick And Easy Paleo Stir-Fries | Paleo Leap

http://allrecipes.com/recipe/11951/linguine-with-clam-sauce/
Linguine with Clam Sauce Recipe - Allrecipes.com

http://www.food.com/recipe/tuscan-vegetarian-pasta-392763?photo=376155
Tuscan Vegetarian Pasta Recipe - Food.com: Food.com

http://www.cheatsheet.com/life/8-deliciously-rustic-pasta-recipes-no-tomato-sauce-required.html/?a=viewall
8 Deliciously Rustic Pasta Recipes, No Tomato Sauce Required

http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/giada-de-laurentiis/penne-with-sun-dried-tomato-pesto-recipe.html
Penne with Sun-Dried Tomato Pesto Recipe : Giada De Laurentiis : Food Network

http://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/mediterranean_tuna_pasta/
Mediterranean Tuna Pasta Recipe | SimplyRecipes.com

http://www.food.com/recipe/chicken-rice-and-spices-bake-105104
Chicken, Rice, And Spices Bake Recipe - Food.com

http://chefsavvy.com/recipes/honey-barbecue-chicken-bites/
Honey Barbecue Chicken Bites - Chef Savvy

http://www.food.com/recipe/simple-easy-stuffed-roast-chicken-with-gravy-for-beginners-101998?nl=email_share
Simple Easy Stuffed Roast Chicken With Gravy For Beginners) Recipe - Food.com

http://www.thekitchn.com/winter-casserole-recipe-simple-shepherds-pie-recipes-from-the-kitchn-179722
Winter Casserole Recipe: Shepherd
s Pie — Recipes from The Kitchn | The Kitchn

http://www.food.com/recipe/my-quot-famous-quot-shredded-chicken-205760
My famous Shredded Chicken Recipe - Food.com
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Petar, definitely what I needed! Now I just need to understand exactly what you did....thanks!

Comment: There a few concepts here that are somewhat advanced, so I'd be happy to answer any questions you might have.